# LINQ sum dates different lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of elements that have list of values with dates. I want to reduce it to just one list sum values for each date.

The list is like this:

```
List
        {
            Values: List of items {
                Value: 1, Date: "2013-01-01"
                Value: 2, Date: "2013-01-02"
                Value: 1, Date: "2013-01-03"
                Value: 0, Date: "2013-01-04"
            }
        },
        {
            Values: List of items {
                Value: 1, Date: "2013-01-01"
                Value: 2, Date: "2013-01-02"
                Value: 1, Date: "2013-01-03"
                Value: 0, Date: "2013-01-04"
            }
        }
```

So I want to have one list with Values that are sum value for each date.

Comment: Whenever you've written "pr", it's unclear - do you mean "per"? (I'm struggling to understand your question.)

Comment: Fixed description with the question on how to sum values from several lists back into one list for each date -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it sounds like you want something like:

```
var sums = from sublist in list
           from item in sublist
           group item by item.Date into g
           select new { Date = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Value) };
```